# Duplicate Entries when updating the DB

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql

My question is as follows, when using postgresql or mongodb if i have new data flowing into the DB can it handle duplicates?
Going more into the details the data is dynamic for example product AAA price 100$ type package, after the initial creation future updates of the data can contain old entries so there is a duplicates issue and also some fields of the older entries might be updated so what i want is only to get the updated data without creating duplicate entries so if the price changes on the older entries that gets updated and if there are newer entries they get inserted.
Is it possible on the DB level or am i asking for too much?

Comment: Postgres can easily handle that using `insert on conflict`

Comment: Thank you! it's exactly what i needed to find out